# How to migrate from `provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)` in Angular 8 to Angular 9

Tags: angular, express, migration, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have a large application that was working with SSR using `ngExpressEngine` in Angular 8.  I ran though all the upgrade procedures described, but my `server.ts` file was not properly migrated. Specifically the reference to `provideModuleMap` remained (which is no longer supported in Angular 9).

Note that my routes were all correctly updated to use the new `.then` system for lazy routes.  Also note that it compiles fine and `ng serve` works correctly.  This problem only arises when I try to run the SSR package from express.

My problem can be isolated to what was, in Angular 8, these lines of code:

```
// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');


  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }));
```

To attempt to get this to work in Angular 9 I removed the call to `provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)` and just passed in `LAZY_MODULE_MAP`, but that doesn't work as it seems `LAZY_MODULE_MAP` isn't generated at all anymore.

...so with my change for Angular 9 I get the typical errors you'd expect from things trying to run server side that can only run client side.  Namely `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

So how do I tell Angular 9 what modules shouldn't be prepared for SSR, as was possible in Angular 8?